# Connecting Zope to Postgres with savepoint support - Alternatives to ZPsycopgDA

Tags: plone, zope, psycopg2

Is there a way to get savepoint support in a Zope connection to Postgres?

I'm currently using ZPsycopgDA, which doesn't support savepoints, and is also hard to install with buildout. Would switching to something like SQLAlchemyDA make things easier?

Background: I've got my users in a postgres database, but when I try look at the history, I get errors about savepoints. That problem is explained here: http://plone.org/products/cmfeditions/issues/46

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that [SQLAlchemyDA](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Products.SQLAlchemyDA/0.4.1) does seem to support savepoints - at least when I switched to it, it did fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend asking in the Plone forums: http://plone.org/support

I'm not using much relational databases myself, but in general you can use collective.tin and other integration products that hook up SQLAlchemy to Plone for content, or if you want to store everything in a relational database, look at RelStorage.

Comment: I should have explained that I have a load of legacy ZSQL scripts, so I need a traditional Zope Database Adapter, so Collective.tin and RelStorage, while nice products aren't relevant in this case.